# GIT - Copy the content of one remote branch to another one

Tags: git, clone, pull, git-remote

I have 2 remote branches (A) and (Z) and the respective local branches (a) and (z).

In branch (A) I have some content (a full project) as in (a), because a is "set up to track remote branch (A) from Origin".

The local branch (z) is also set up to track remote branch (Z) but is empty.

My question is: how can I copy the content of remote branch (A) to remote branch (Z) so that in local branch (z) I get the same content as local branch (a).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean your z branch is empty? If you do not care about the contents of Z and z just delete both and start from scratch:

Delete z branch:

```
git branch -d z
```

Delete remote Z branch and prune local repo

```
git push origin :Z

git remote prune origin
```

Create new branch z from origin/A and checkout it

```
git checkout -b z origin/A
```

Push new branch to origin/Z with tracking

```
git push -u origin Z
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have an existing local branch `z` where you want to copy the code of branch `a` then you can use either `merge` or `rebase` command.

Merge:

`git checkout z`

`git merge a`

`git push origin z`

Rebase;

`git checkout z`

`git rebase a`

`git push origin z`

If you do not have existing local branch, then you can create a new branch from branch `a` and in this case your local branch will have same code as your branch `a`. This is best way to do that.

- I would prefer to delete my local branch `z` and will be creating a new branch `z` against branch `a`.To do that:

`git branch -d z` // It will only delete local branch

`git checkout a`

`git checkout -b z`

`git push origin z`